# Having custom classes validate as slots are added

Tags: r

Lets say I want to make a class "myClass" with two slots A and B.

now I want a validObject function that ensures A and B are the same length

```
same_length <- function(object){
    if(length(object@A)!=length(object@B)) {
        "vectors are not the same length"
     } else TRUE
}

setClass("myClass", representation(A="numeric", B="numeric"),
          validity=same_length)
```

I saw a function somewhere that will ensure the class is valid when initialized:

```
setMethod("initialize", "myClass", function(.Object, ...){
    value <- callNextMethod()
    validObject(value)
    value
})
```

which will send an error if I try

> newObj <- new("myClass", A=c(1,2,3), B=c(1,2))

But if I do

```
newObj <- new("myClass")
newObj@A <- c(1,2,3)
newObj@B <- c(1,2)
```

no error is thrown. How do I get it to throw an error as soon as a new slot assignment does not validate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a 'replacement method' that does the check. To do this, we need to create a generic function (because no function with the appropriate name and signature already exists)

```
setGeneric("slotA<-", function(x, ..., value) standardGeneric("slotA<-"))
```

We then need to implement the replacement method for the specific types of objects we want to handle -- the first argument is of class 'myClass', the second argument (`value`) is of class 'numeric':

```
setReplaceMethod("slotA", c("myClass", "numeric"), function(x, ..., value) {
    x@A = value
    validObject(x)
    x
})
```

We might also write a 'getter' generic and method

```
setGeneric("slotA", function(x, ...) standardGeneric("slotA"))
setMethod("slotA", "myClass", function(x, ...) x@A)
```

and then

```
> a=new("myClass", A=1:10, B=10:1)
> slotA(a)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> slotA(a) = 1:5
Error in validObject(x) : 
  invalid class "myClass" object: vectors are not the same length
```

Note that the default `initialize` method calls `checkValidity`, so if you use `callNextMethod` as the last line in your constructor there's no need to explicitly check validity.

Comment: Could you explain what the difference between using setGeneric() and setMethod would be in this case?